# How to make MySQL Workbench to ask me to confirm before deleting?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

The title says it all. I want to change the setting in MySQL Workbench so that whenver I delete/update/truncate/drop somethings, it will show a popup window asking me to confirm. I think this is the default setting but I turn it off a long time ago and cannot find a way to revert back to the defaul setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for "Safe Updates" in the Workbench preferences?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-preferences-sql-editor.html

I don't think that will prompt for TRUNCATE or DROP, nor will it prompt when you do *any* DELETE or UPDATE. Only DELETE or UPDATE with no WHERE clause.

Comment: yes that's the one, thanks. I wish they have a feature to ask for confirmation for all delete/update/truncate/drop.